# How to ignore multiple classes using the :not selector?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have this selector below where it ignores any `li` with the class `show-all-boxes`

```
$('.boxes li:not([class="show-all-boxes"]) input:checkbox')
```

What is the best way of adding multiple classes to be ignored by the selector? An example of this that I thought would work but it doesn't is:

```
$('.boxes li:not([class="show-all-boxes, show-all-circles, show-all-triangles"]) input:checkbox')
```

Answer (score 114, accepted):

The :not selector can take multiple CSS selectors as arguments ( http://api.jquery.com/not-selector ). E.g.

```
$('div:not(.a,.b)').empty()
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HFfcP/

Comment: no problem Cecil. btw, your second code was not working because it seems to trying to match on all `li`s that do not have the class "show-all-boxes, show-all-circles, show-all-triangles" (commas and all). http://jsfiddle.net/56uKS/

Answer (score 6):

try this :

```
$('.boxes li').not(".show-all-boxes, .show-all-circles, .show-all-triangles").find('input:checkbox')
```