# What is the difference between these two selectors using “:not”?

Tags: css, css-selectors

What is the difference between these two selectors?

```css
input:not([type="radio"][type="submit"])
input:not([type="radio"]):not([type="submit"])
```

Will an `<input>` tag that has no `type` attribute be selected?

I’ve read:

- [Css pseudo classes input:not(disabled)not:[type="submit"]:focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9207304/css-pseudo-classes-inputnotdisablednottype-submitfocus)
- [CSS: multiple attribute selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12340737/css-multiple-attribute-selector)

Comment: Waw this is a tough one. I was testing (and accidentally posted an answer) that shows that neither of them actually target any elements - and after reading the specification for `:not`, it does not clarify whether they could be chained. It says they can't be nested, but thats it... I am wondering whether it is tripping up over the double `type`, but I can't find a good way to prove this. Good question!

Comment: Of course, `:not` can be chained, why shouldn't?

Comment: Thank you for your editing, Xufox! You made this much better.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quoting [the Selector Level 4 docs](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#negation):

> The negation pseudo-class, `:not()`, is a functional pseudo-class taking
>   *a selector list* as an argument. It represents an element that is not
>   represented by its argument.
>
> **Note: In Selectors Level 3, only a single simple selector was allowed
>   as the argument to `:not()`**.

That explains why this...

```
input:not([type="radio"][type="submit"])
```

... is not supported in any browser that doesn't implement this part of CSS4 specs (as far as I know, no one does at this point of time; it's only a working draft, after all). But the logic is flawed in this selector, too: even if syntax was supported universally, it should have been written as...

```
input:not([type="radio"],[type="submit"])
```

See, `[foo][bar]` rule is treated as requirement for any element to be *both* `foo` and `bar`. But (of course!) it's not possible for any input to be both of `radio` and `submit` type.

The bottom line: you'll have to use...

```
input:not([type="radio"]):not([type="submit"])
```

... because [CSS3 only supports simple selectors](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-3/#negation) in `:not`.

Comment: Thanks for answer my question. Of course, there is **no** `<input>` tag that has [type="radio"] and [type="submit"] both. Then does `input:not([type="radio"][type="submit"])` select all the `<input>` tags?

Comment: And one more question; do these two selectors select **an `<input>` tag that does not have a `type` attribute**?

Comment: > Then does input:not([type="radio"][type="submit"]) select all the <input> tags? - No, it doesn't, unless CSS4 is supported. If the latter, it's exactly because you supply `:not` with ever-non-matching selector.

Comment: > And one more question; do these two selectors select an <input> tag that does not have a type attribute? - Sure, and that's easy [to prove](http://jsfiddle.net/oksbynu8/). )

Answer (score 2):

This line seems to be invalid, as multiple `[]` don't seem to pass the W3C validation service for CSS:

```
input:not([type="radio"][type="submit"])
```

This line, however, is valid and simply excludes any element of either of the two types, but selects any other that is an `input`:

```
input:not([type="radio"]):not([type="submit"])
```

I can't find any evidence for it in the documentation on the `:not` selector however. If you want to test validation, heres a link to the W3C Validator: https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/ .

Now, lets test this in a snippet

```css
input {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
#valid input:not([type="radio"]):not([type="submit"]){
  border-color: red;
}
#invalid input:not([type="radio"][type="submit"]){
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="valid">
  <pre><strong>Valid:</strong> input:not([type="radio"]):not([type="submit"])</pre>
  <input type="text" />
  <input type="submit" />
  <input type="radio" />
</div>
<div id="invalid">
  <pre><strong>Invalid:</strong> input:not([type="radio"][type="submit"])</pre>
  <input type="text" />
  <input type="submit" />
  <input type="radio" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

here i just try for the difference

i tried 4 ways in the below jsfiddle as you can see with the comments in

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    
    //applied using jquery
    
    $('.usingJquery input:not([type="radio"],[type="submit"])').css({
        'background-color' : 'cadetblue',
        'border' : 'dotted #7FFF00'
    });
})
```

```css
input {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
}

/*will apply the only first one so border and background will be applied all input types exluding radio type*/
input:not([type="radio"]) , input:not([type="submit"]){
    border:1px solid grey;
    background-color : green;
}

/*this will not work as you can not apply multiple in same parantheses as i think*/
input:not([type="radio"][type="submit"]){
    border:1px solid green;
}

/*as i think for above code i tried using " , (comma)" seprator but it also didn't work*/
input:not([type="radio"],[type="submit"]){
    border:1px solid aqua;
}

/*this will work as you can see */
input:not([type="radio"]):not([type="submit"]){
    border:1px solid red;   
    background-color : yellow;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio">
<input type="submit">
<input type="file">
<input type="text">
<input type="checkbox">

    <div class="usingJquery">
        <input type="radio">
        <input type="submit">
        <input type="file">
        <input type="text">
        <input type="checkbox">
    </div>
```

and here is the demo code for this explaination

**[See Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HSKPx/322/)**

and what i found is from 2 questions of the jsfiddle that are linked below

[Refer for  input:not(selector):not(selector)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5684160/multiple-not-selector)

> And if you want to try **input:not([type="radio"][type="submit"])** selector using jquery with comma **","** separation for that you may refer

[Refer for using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8699366/how-to-ignore-multiple-classes-using-the-not-selector)